# Is there a function in the Google Docs API that lets one get information on the headings in a doc?

Tags: google-docs-api

I am trying to help out an associate (also a non-developer) scope out the possibilities for a tool that will gather metadata on the documents in a Google Docs account.  One of the types of information they want to access is the metadata about about styles used in the document (e.g., Title and Heading styles).  This data could be used to create a master Table of Contents for a particular collection.

I found the [API Reference](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/) section on the [Google Drive SDK site](https://developers.google.com/drive/), but it does not seem to contain any information about styles or headings.  Does this capability exist in some other form, or somewhere else?  If not, does anyone have any suggestions on a more brute force way to get this information?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like something that could be done with the newer Google Drive API and the indexableText attribute:
https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files#resource

your script would need to parse the document content and determine the indexable text including headings, section titles, etc and put the strings in the indexableText attribute to allow Google Drive search to locate the files based on this data.

Comment: Thanks, Jay.  Reading the documentation on that, I agree that perhaps this could be used, as inefficient as it seems: generating my own metadata by parsing the full content of the documents and then storing it in some sort of copy of the whole library (since the indexableText attribute is an attribute of a document), or re-writing all the user's documents with this updated metadata.  But reading this information also made me feel that the API does not provide this metadata in the first place, which is too bad.